# Can I use both ましょう and ですか?

Tags: grammar, politeness, questions

I want to ask someone a question as to whether they want to do something.

> Would you like to play Minecraft on the computer?

Would this be written as

> コンピューターでマインクラフトをあそびましょうか。

OR

> コンピューターでマインクラフトをあそびましょうですか。

?

Is there any difference between these two or is the second one just grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Though this is not the main part of the question, `マインクラフトをあそぶ` is not idiomatic. You can say `マインクラフトをする`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use it like this.

です is used after い-adjectives or な-adjectives or nouns, making it polite. The non-polite form would be だ or nothing for な-adj and nouns, or nothing at all for  い-adj.

The ましょう construct in question is one of the conjugations of Japanese ***verbs***, namely the volitional form in its polite version. The non-polite volitional form would be simply *おう.

です can NEVER go with ***verbs***.

Example:

> Polite:　僕は学生です　Non-polite:　僕は学生 / 僕は学生だ
> Polite:　風が強いです　Non-polite:　風が強い　
> Polite: 歌を歌いましょう！学校に行きましょう！　Non-polite: 歌を歌おう！学校に行こう！

The following is wrong:

> 歌を歌いましょうです！　or 　歌を歌おうです！